# FormView insert hidden parameters based on dropdownlist selection

Tags: asp.net

I have a FormView which I populate using SqlDataSource1. I do databinding like:

```
Text='<%# Bind("EffectiveDate") %>'
```

`FormView` also contain a dropdownlist with a custom `SqldataSource2`.  Dropdown list contains list of cities. User is able to change a value in dropdown.

Once I submit a form I have to send to PowerShell script some parameters which I supposed to hide like street, ZipCode, etc... On first form load I can bind this parameters to hidden fields from `SqlDataSource1`. But if user change a value in dropdownlist I have to rebind parameters. Have no idea yet how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the drop down list to do a post back.

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

and then on Page Load or Selection changed event you can set up the hidden field.

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            hfSomething.Value = ddlSomething.SelectedValue;
        }
        else
        {
            //data binding code
        }
    }
```